# Find a row in a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a table in a DataSet and I want to search for a row in this Table using a unique key.

My question is : Is there any method that allows me to find this row without using loops ?

This is the code I wrote using the forech loop :

```
foreach (var myRow in myClass.ds.Tables["Editeur"].AsEnumerable())
{
     if (newKeyWordAEditeurName == myRow[1] as String)
         id_Editeur_Editeur = (int)myRow[0];
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure. You have the Select method off of a DataTable. GEt the table from your DataSet, and use Select to snag it.

```
void Demo(DataSet ds)
{
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]; // refer to your table of interest within the DataSet

    dt.Select("Field = 1"); // replace with your criteria as appropriate
}
```

Comment: Is the Select method returns a DataRow ? because when I can't cast it to Int32

Comment: Yes, Select returns an array of DataRow objects (DataRow[]). The columns in each Row contain the fields in each record returned by the Select.

Comment: But I want to get just one row because the field I used to search for this row is unique

Comment: Then the criteria you specify in the argument to the Select should return a DataRow array of just one element, eg DataRow[0].

Comment: I tried this : `var myRow = myClass.ds.Tables["Editeur"].Select(String.Format("ID = {0}", "test"));
 id_Editeur_Editeur = (int)myRow[0][0];` but I got this error : 
`Cannot find the column [test] `

Comment: The format of your select statement is not quite right. You need to put quotes around the target field, eg String.Format("ID = ""{0}""","test");. Without the quotes, Select interprets the word "test" as a column name, which isn't in your result set. That's the *value* you want from the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

To find a particular row, you might want to search by key which can uniquely identify each row.
But if you want to find a group of rows, then you want to use filter.

Key can contain different types of objects simultaneously.  So can filter!

Following is a concrete example which covers searching with a key method or a filter method as locateOneRow() and locateRows() respectively.

```
using System.Data;
namespace namespace_A {
  public static class cData    {
     public static DataTable srchTBL = new DataTable(tableName: "AnyTable");
     public static DataColumn[] theColumns = {
     new DataColumn("IDnum", typeof(int))
     , new DataColumn("IDString", typeof(string))
     , new DataColumn("DataString", typeof(string))
     };
     public static void DataInit(){
        if (srchTBL.Columns.Count == 0) {
           srchTBL.Columns.AddRange(theColumns);
           srchTBL.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[2] { srchTBL.Columns["IDnum"], srchTBL.Columns["IDstring"] };
        //Data
           srchTBL.Rows.Add(0, "me", "Homemaker");
           srchTBL.Rows.Add(1, "me2", "Breadwinner2");
           srchTBL.Rows.Add(1, "you", "Breadwinner1");
           srchTBL.Rows.Add(2, "kid", "Learner");
        }
     }//DataInit
     public static DataRow locateOneRow(){
        DataInit();
        object[] keyVals = new object[] {0, "me" };
        return srchTBL.Rows.Find(keyVals);
     }//locateOneRow - Result: the "Homemaker" row
     public static DataRow[] locateRows(){ //no Primary key needed
        DataInit();
        return srchTBL.Select("IDnum = 1 OR IDstring = 'me'");
     }//locateRows - Result: the row with "Homermaker" & the row with "Breadwinner2"  
   }//class
   class Program    {
      static void Main(string[] args)       {
      try
      {
          DataRow row1 =cData.locateOneRow();
          DataRow[] rows = cData.locateRows();
      }catch(Exception ex){
     
      }
    } // Main
  } // Program
}
```